Why are the download links on my site downloading an html-only .htm file of my index.php instead of the pdf it's linking to?
I learned html, css, and php, and used them to rebuild our company's site from the ground up, all in the course of about a month and a half. Whether due to my inexperience or rush job, or both, I've been struggling with spaghetti and many issues with the site. Part of what this site is supposed to do is serve as a web interface to view and download pdfs that we have saved in the site's repository.
File structure: The files are saved in "documents" (permission code 0755) in the home folder. This is at the same level as public_html. Then, within public_html, I have a subfolder called "prints" that holds this particular part of the site.
The host: I am using a site hosted by GoDaddy, and the backend is accessed via cPanel for the files and phpMyAdmin for the SQL databases.
Download button code: Here, $searchResults[$i]['extension'] is the full relative filepath of the file in question that is pulled from an SQL table (something like ../../documents/address/suite number/file name). I've confirmed this filepath is correct and that the file exists (at least for the files I'm using to test).
<a href="' . $searchResults[$i]['extension'] . '" class="file-download-table-row" download>Download</a>
I've also tried making the download button like this:
<a href="downloadpdf.php?file=' . $searchResults[$i]['extension'] . '" class="file-download-table-row">Download</a>
and then having a downloadpdf.php file based on some code I grabbed on GFG:
<?php
header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream"); 

$file_path = $_GET["file"] . ".pdf";
if (!file_exists($file_path)) {
    die("File not found");
}

header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=" . urlencode($file_path));    
header("Content-Type: application/pdf"); 
header("Content-Description: File Transfer");             
header("Content-Length: " . filesize($file_path)); 

flush(); // This doesn't really matter. 

$fp = fopen($file_path, "r"); 
while (!feof($fp)) { 
    echo fread($fp, 65536); 
    flush(); // This is essential for large downloads 
}  

fclose($fp);

The problem: In both variations of my code, the anchor either links to or downloads a .htm that is just an html-only version of my public_html/index.php. This all worked when I tested locally, but this behavior started when I made the push to live. My best guess is that this is some sort of permissions issue, but the only remedy to this that I know of is to ensure that every folder and file in the path has permission code 0755. Of course, I've already tried this to no avail.
I've tried an anchor linking directly to the relative file path, and I've tried one that links to a php file I grabbed off Geeks For Geeks that sets up a pdf download. I expected to download the pdf file that exists in the given path, and this is what happened on local testing, but the behavior changed on pushing to live (story of my life lately, lol).
Edit: I've moved documents inside public_html and updated my SQL records accordingly. I now have <a href="downloadpdf.php?print-id=' . $searchResults[$i]['print_number'] . '&building-id=' . $buildingID . '" target="_blank" class="file-download-table-row">Download</a> for my download button.
The downloadpdf.php code:
<?php
include ("downloadpdf_model.php");
include ("dbh.inc.php");


$recordID = $_GET["print-id"];

if(!isset($_GET['building-id']) || empty($_GET['building-id']) || !isset($_SESSION['print-id']) || empty($_SESSION['print-id'])){
    header('Location: view-buildings.php');
    $pdo = null;
    $stmt = null;
    exit();
}

if($_SESSION['user_level'] === 16 || in_array($_GET['building-id'], $_SESSION['assigned_buildings'])){

    $file_path = getExtensionFromID($pdo, $recordID);

    header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream"); 
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=" . urlencode($file_path));    
    header("Content-Type: application/download"); 
    header("Content-Description: File Transfer");             
    header("Content-Length: " . filesize($file_path)); 
    readFile($file_path);

    flush(); // This doesn't really matter. 

    $fp = fopen($file_path, "r"); 
    while (!feof($fp)) { 
        echo fread($fp, 65536); 
        flush(); // This is essential for large downloads 
    }  

    fclose($fp);
}else{
    header("Location: ../prints/login.php");
}

The downloadpdf_model.php code:
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

function getExtensionFromID(object $pdo, int $recordID){
    $query = "SELECT extension FROM prints WHERE print_number=:printID";
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare($query);
    $stmt->bindParam(':printID', $recordID);
    $stmt->execute();
    $extension = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)
    return $extension['extension'];
}

I updated the button to open in a new tab, but otherwise the behavior remains unchanged: I am still being sent to an html-only index.php page (where the url is the downloadpdf.php).

Sounds like you might have some URL rewriting (via .htaccess / mod_rewrite / etc) that is intercepting the request. FYI your downloadpdf.php approach is the right one but I would pass a record ID or similar, then lookup the file path in the DB. Accepting arbitrary file paths in the request is very bad for security

What does your domain root point to? Usually that would be set to public_html, which means you can not access folders outside of it via HTTP. So linking to a download file with ../../documents/, when that documents folder is located on the same level as public_html, can't work. (And I am guessing your system is configured to just show the index.php as "error document" in such a case, which would explain why what actually gets download is the content of that.)

Domain root is public_html. Whoever built the site before me (prior to it breaking) somehow got this to work despite the structure, because all those filepaths in our database link from the prints folder to the documents folder exactly as it is now. Also, thanks for the catch on arbitrary file paths. That would've been really stupid of me to leave in.

@Phil I've made some of the suggested changes, but still running into the same behavior (see edited post). When I was testing, I had the permission set to 0755 but now that I have to put this aside I've temporarily changed it to 0700. Correct me if I'm wrong, but now that it's in public_html, if I left it at 0755, anyone that knew the file path of a document could entire it as a url and see it?
